# Significance of link address 2000 8000 7C00;

Tags: linux

Can you explain to me the significance of link address 2000 8000 7C00? It's  in a MACRO from the GRUB configure script, which checks whether OBJCOPY works for absolute addresses.

Here's the snippet of the code:

```
AC_DEFUN([grub_PROG_OBJCOPY_ABSOLUTE],
[AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether ${OBJCOPY} works for absolute addresses])
AC_CACHE_VAL(grub_cv_prog_objcopy_absolute,
[cat > conftest.c <<\EOF
void
cmain (void)
{
   *((int *) 0x1000) = 2;
}
EOF

if AC_TRY_EVAL(ac_compile) && test -s conftest.o; then :
else
  AC_MSG_ERROR([${CC-cc} cannot compile C source code])
fi
grub_cv_prog_objcopy_absolute=yes
for link_addr in 2000 8000 7C00; do
  if AC_TRY_COMMAND([${CC-cc} ${CFLAGS} -nostdlib -Wl,-N -Wl,-Ttext -Wl,$link_addr conftest.o -o conftest.exec]); then :
  else
    AC_MSG_ERROR([${CC-cc} cannot link at address $link_addr])
  fi
  if AC_TRY_COMMAND([${OBJCOPY-objcopy} -O binary conftest.exec conftest]); then :
  else
    AC_MSG_ERROR([${OBJCOPY-objcopy} cannot create binary files])
  fi
  if test ! -f conftest.old || AC_TRY_COMMAND([cmp -s conftest.old conftest]); then
    mv -f conftest conftest.old
  else
    grub_cv_prog_objcopy_absolute=no
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: I can't help you with 2000 and 8000, but `0x7C00` is the address where the BIOS loads the Master Boot Record to. Google "7C00 mbr" will produce more reading and better explanations. I couldn't find anything for `0x2000` and `0x8000` right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [gnu.org - Hacking GRUB](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/grub-0.90/html_chapter/grub_22.html)

> GRUB consists of two distinct components, called stages, which are
>   loaded at different times in the boot process. Because they run
>   mutual-exclusively, sometimes a memory area overlaps with another
>   memory area. And, even in one stage, a single memory area can be used
>   for various purposes, because their usages are mutually exclusive.

`0x7C00` Stage 1 is loaded here by BIOS or another boot loader

`0x2000` The optional Stage 1.5 is loaded here / Command-line buffer for Multiboot kernels and modules

`0x8000` Stage2 is loaded here